# Oauth2 without MVC in webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0

I've got a web forms application that i need to integrate Facebook, google and twitter log in but what I've found with all the tutorials is that my solution does not have Startup.auth.cs, and then when i implement a Owin class and try to call

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication
```

i get the error that owin.iappbuilder doesn't contain the definition.

I am using a 4.5 .net framework and do not have MVC so any help would be great.

I have been stuck on this error for quite some time so getting past this with help or a direction to a tutorial will be a great relief

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project) for a tutorial on how to do this. You want this part:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebFormsIdentity.Startup))]

namespace WebFormsIdentity
{
   public class Startup
   {
      public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
      {
         // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
         app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
         {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login")
         });
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you authenticate through facebook using this method? because when i include app.UseFacebookAuthentication( i get an error saying it does not exist

Comment: You need to add the `Owin.Facebook` package and add (please note this comes from memory and might not be exact) `using Microsoft.AspNet.Owin.Facebook`

Comment: Worked a charm, Thank you :)